# Pagination in Yii without database

Tags: php, yii, pagination

How can I add pagination to content what not getting from DB? For example: I has cicle what 20 times output some lines, how I can paginate it. I try to create paginator and it display properly count of pages but in each pages I see all content.

Code of loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $day = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - $i);
    $elems = ContentItem::dayNews($day);
    $test[] = $elems;
    if (count($elems)) {
        $date = Y::date_print($day, 'd-m-Y');
        $arr = explode('-', $date);
        ?>
        <div class="news_dhead">
            <?= Y::isToday($day) ? 'Today, ' : '' ?>
            <?= Y::isYesterday($day) ? 'Yesterday, ' : '' ?>
            <? echo $arr[0] . ' ' . Y::months($arr[1]) . ' ' . $arr[2] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="news_dcoll">
        <?
        foreach ($elems as $key => $elem) {
            ?>
            <div class="ib news_delem">
                <? //echo $key;?>
                <div class="news_ddate"><?= Y::date_print($elem->cdate, 'H.i') ?></div>
                <a href="<?= $elem->urlNews ?>" class="tdn"><?= $elem->title ?></a>
            </div>
        <?
        }
        ?></div><?
    }
}
```

So how you can see, each row is the list of data what gets from db. PS. Loop write another man.

Comment: You can add custom data to a dataprovider and let [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)/[CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) paginate it for you? There's a similar answer here: [How to create my own DataProvider in Yii using CDataProvider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739588/how-to-create-my-own-dataprovider-in-yii-using-cdataprovider)

Comment: @Stu, but i dont wand to use grid or list views, I added all my items to array and try to call pager on array bu still get same results

Comment: CListView does just that, cycles through the array and outputs each line at a time and does the pagination automatically for you, I'm sure that's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets is Yii use a data provider to show data. There are different data providers:

1. [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) (CActiveDataProvider implements a data provider based on ActiveRecord. )
2. [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) (CArrayDataProvider implements a data provider based on a raw data array. )
3. [CDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) (CDataProvider is a base class that implements the IDataProvider interface.)

You can use `CDataProvider` or `CArrayDataProvider` in cases that you don't have any db data and pass it through your widget(Or use it anywhere)

Comment: I dont need to use this providers, because how I know they retrieve pager with display data, and i need only pager. I add loop what represents data to my question...

Comment: @excluded_once umm, how about http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager ?

Comment: what the difference if I still need to use Pagination class with Criteria ?

Comment: No, you can not to use criteria, take a look at this example: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50862-clinkpager-without-cdbcriteria/